# Horizontal view switching like in the official Google plus app

Tags: android

Anyone have a code sample of horizontal view switching like in the official Google plus app. Im mean were you switch between  Nearby - Circles - Incomming in the Stream view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're talking about is [ViewPager.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)
It requires this [Android compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

I recommend looking into [Jake Wharton's library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) and then taking a look at [Mark Allison's examples of styling it](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help you http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [ActionBar Sherlock Library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for this